# extract months in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

Hello please does anyone have an idea how I could extract
the month from a date variable in R data frame.

I tried the lubridate function but it doesn't work or am I getting the syntax wrong;

```
   NTData$Monthfull = lubridate::month(NTData$Truckoutdate, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
```

Where the `NTData` is my data and the `Truckoutdate` is where I am trying to extract my data from.

it keeps telling me my dataframe is atomic and the `$` function can only be used in a recursive data frame

Please how can any one be of assistance.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, probably Truckoutdate is not a date

Comment: Try copy pasting the output of `dput(head(NTData$Monthfull))` into your question. This will help others see what you're working with.

Comment: The first use of `$` is attempting to apply to `NTData`. If it's not a dataframe or list then it will fail with that sort of error.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).